# How to match only the first element of a given type based on their position among a group of siblings

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, element

Please find below of the partial source code below:

```
</td><td class="zentriert"><a href="/statistik/transferrekorde?saison_id=12%2F13&amp;plus=0">12/13</a></td><td class="zentriert">
<img src="https://tmssl.akamaized.net//images/flagge/verysmall/26.png?lm=1520611569" title="Brazil" alt="Brazil" class="flaggenrahmen" /><br />
<img src="https://tmssl.akamaized.net//images/flagge/verysmall/50.png?lm=1520611569" title="France" alt="France" class="flaggenrahmen" />
</td>
<td class="">
<table class="inline-table">
    <tr>
```

In this case, I just want to retrieve Brazil.

I identified that there is always `<br />` in front of the second nationality, but the condition of if nat.previous_sibling != `'<br />'` does not work as intended, it is still retrieving Brazil and France.

I will need to iterate the list for other players’ nationalities, so find() is not applicable in this scenario.

Any helps are greatly appreciated.

The soup code I used:

```
for nationality in pageSoup.find_all('td', attrs={'class': 'zentriert'}):
    nat_des = nationality.descendants
    for nat in nat_des:
        if nat.name == 'img' and nat.get('class', '') == ['flaggenrahmen']:
            if nat.previous_sibling != '<br />':
                print(nat.previous_sibling)
```

Comment: Do you still need the other nationalities or can the code just return the Brazil line?

Comment: Just the Nationality on the top, which in this case only Brazil.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you looped through `nationality.decendents`?

Also, it is probably a good idea to see the other answer for a cleaner way to work toward your desired result.

Here's a solution using your strategy. This loops through `nationality` and uses [find_previous_sibling()](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-previous-siblings-and-find-previous-sibling). Since there is no previous sibling for the first image, we need to check for `None`

Try this:

```py
for nationality in soup.find_all('td', attrs={'class': 'zentriert'}):
    for nat in nationality:
        if nat.name == 'img':
            if nat.get('class', '') == ['flaggenrahmen']:
                prev = nat.find_previous_sibling()
                if prev is None or prev.name != 'br':
                    print(f'Image to process is {nat}')
```

Result:

```
Image to process is <img alt="Brazil" class="flaggenrahmen" src="https://tmssl.akamaized.net//images/flagge/verysmall/26.png?lm=1520611569" title="Brazil"/>
```

Comment: Wow setting previous siblings as none, pretty slick! Thanks, I am gonna try it. In the complete source code there are more nationalities to loop through, and I just looked at some tutorial that instructed the use of decendents.

Answer (score 0):

*Work with select to get the first title*

> ```
> elements = soup.select('td.zentriert img:nth-of-type(1)')
> ```

*Example*

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '<td class="zentriert"><a href="/statistik/transferrekorde?saison_id=12%2F13&amp;plus=0">12/13</a></td>' \
       '<td class="zentriert"><img src="https://tmssl.akamaized.net//images/flagge/verysmall/26.png?lm=1520611569" title="Brazil" alt="Brazil" class="flaggenrahmen" /><br />' \
       '<img src="https://tmssl.akamaized.net//images/flagge/verysmall/50.png?lm=1520611569" title="France" alt="France" class="flaggenrahmen" /></td>' \
       '<td class=""><table class="inline-table"><tr>' \


soup = BeautifulSoup(html, features="lxml")
elements = soup.select('td.zentriert img:nth-of-type(1)')


for item in elements:
    b = item.get('title')
    print(b)
```

---

> *Which will output just **`Brazil`***

Comment: Is it possible to generate all the lists at the same time, for other people that have dual nationalities as well?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a cleaner way to do it.

The following code makes these assumptions:

- The required `td` elements must have `zentriert` class
- The first image element with `flaggenrahmen` class is to be returned

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<td class="zentriert">
    <a href="/statistik/transferrekorde?saison_id=12%2F13&amp;plus=0">12/13</a>
</td>
<td class="zentriert">
    <img src="..." title="Brazil" alt="Brazil" class="flaggenrahmen" /><br />
    <img src="..." title="France" alt="France" class="flaggenrahmen" />
</td>
<td class="nothing">
    <img src="..." title="Japan" alt="Japan" class="flaggenrahmen" /><br />
    <img src="..." title="Mexico" alt="Mexico" class="flaggenrahmen" />
</td>
<td class="zentriert">
    <img src="..." title="India" alt="India" class="flaggenrahmen" /><br />
    <img src="..." title="France" alt="France" class="flaggenrahmen" />
</td>
<td class="zentriert">
    <img src="..." title="Italy" alt="Italy" /><br />
    <img src="..." title="France" alt="France" class="flaggenrahmen" />
    <img src="..." title="Iraq" alt="Iraq" class="flaggenrahmen" />
</td>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
td = soup.select('td.zentriert')

for items in td:
    nationality = items.select('img.flaggenrahmen')
    if nationality:
        print(nationality[0].get('title'))
```

Result:

```
Brazil
India
France
```